How to serialize one property of an object of arrays
I have the following model
public class MyModel {
    public string Title;
    public string Description;
    public string Date;
}

I now have an IEnumerable object containing many MyModels
{
    data: [
        {
            Title: xxx,
            Description: yyy,
            Date: 2024-12-03
        },
        {
            Title: xxx,
            Description: yyy,
            Date: 2024-12-04
        },
        {
            Title: xxx,
            Description: yyy,
            Date: 2024-12-05
        },
        {
            Title: xxx,
            Description: yyy,
            Date: 2024-12-06
        }
    ]
}

What I would like to do is to serialize just the dates. How would I go about this? The following obviously doesn't work.
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.date)


What do you want the output JSON to look like?

What library are you using? For system.text.json, see How to ignore properties.

If data is a collection of MyModel instances and you want just a collection of string instances of a single property of that model, you can use .Select() to project the former into the latter.  For example:
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.Select(d => d.Date));


So simple.I am new to C#, migrating over from PHP, so I knew there would be a quick way to do it. I just didn't know the syntax. Thanks so much for your help


Note, this answer assumes your model class uses Properties, not Fields. Your current posted code uses Fields. I'd suggest you change to Properties.

It depends on what you want the output to look like.
If you want the output to be an array of objects, where each object contains a Date property (this would be the same format as what you currently have, just removing all the other object properties), such as:
[
  { "Date": "2024-12-03" },
  { "Date": "2024-12-04" },
  // etc...
]

then you need to create and pass a new datatype to SerializeObject that only has the Date C# property. The easiest way to do this is with an anonymous type (new { ... }) in conjunction with LINQ's Select.
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.Select(x => new {
    Date = x.Date // you could also just do "x.Date"
});

If you had the need for it, you could create your own concrete class for the minimal data. This allows you to reuse it elsewhere.
class MyModelMinimal
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
}

// ...

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.Select(x => new MyModelMinimal 
{
    Date = x.Date
});

You might also be able to "ignore" the other properties in your model by applying a [JsonIgnore] attribute (ensure it's the right attribute for Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json), however I suspect that you use MyModel for deserializing JSON as well, so ignoring properties would interfere with the the deserializing result.
If you want the output to be an array of strings, where each string is the value of the Date C# property:
[
  "2024-12-03",
  "2024-12-04",
  // etc...
]

you can modify the above to project only the Date property as a string rather than projecting a new object with a Date property.
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.Select(x => x.Date);

As you are new to C#, the following is (practically) the same thing:
List<string> dateValues = new List<string>();

foreach (var model in data)
{
    dateValues.Add(model.Date);
}

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dateValues);

And this is the equivalent of the first option using the custom class:
List<MyModelMinimal> newModels = new List<MyModelMinimal>();

foreach (var model in data)
{
    MyModelMinimal newModel = new MyModelMinimal
    {
        Date = model.Date;
    };
    newModels .Add(newModel);
}

var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newModels);

LINQ lets you do collection manipulation with less code.

You can use LINQ to extract the dates from your IEnumerable and then serialize the resulting list of dates. Here's how you can do it:
var dates = data.Select(m => m.Date);
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dates);

This will give you a JSON string containing an array of dates:
["2024-12-03", "2024-12-04", "2024-12-05", "2024-12-06"]


To serialize just the dates from your IEnumerable<MyModel>, you can follow these steps:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class MyModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var data = new List<MyModel>
        {
            new MyModel { Title = "xxx", Description = "yyy", Date = "2024-12-03" },
            new MyModel { Title = "xxx", Description = "yyy", Date = "2024-12-04" },
            new MyModel { Title = "xxx", Description = "yyy", Date = "2024-12-05" },
            new MyModel { Title = "xxx", Description = "yyy", Date = "2024-12-06" }
        };

        // Extract the dates
        var dates = data.Select(model => model.Date);

        // Serialize the dates
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dates);

        // Output the serialized dates
        Console.WriteLine(serialized);
    }
}

